# caliburn micro and obfuscation

Tags: wpf, obfuscation, caliburn.micro

I am using caliburn micro with my WPF applicaion. I found that when I obfuscation my application, it doesn't work as caliburn micro is using reflection and obfuscation change the names and hence caliburn micro can not work.

Is there any workaround for this? Is there any obfuscation software around that can do this?

Comment: It works without problems for me.
Do you use custom interfaces inherited from Caliburn.Micro.IHandle?

Comment: @Egor4eg: No I didnot. Which tool do you use for this?

Comment: I have used http://www.eziriz.com/intellilock.htm with  caliburn micro #1.5.0 which was released in March. Maybe you should try to update your version of caliburn?

Comment: The only problem I had was related to the fact that I used my own interfaces derived from IHandle<T>

Answer (score 0):

I use caliburn micro with my obfuscator (SmartAssembly) and I had to configure the obfuscation to exclude everything in the View and ViewModel namespace.